# Is "get stuck" a proper term in academic writing?

Tags: expressions, science, academia, scientific-language

I am writing to inquire the usage of "get stuck" in academic writing. Here is my draft:

> this design could get stuck in a bad local minima and therefore is not desired.

I use Google Scholar to search "get stuck" and I do find quite a number of exact matchings. However, I still want to double check if there was any (more) proper term in this context. Thank you very much!

Comment: To me "get + past participle" seems colloquial, and I would not use it in formal writing, especially in that context. (PS note that "a bad local minima" is a horrible mistake.)

Comment: Minima is plural. Minimum is singular, And as math concepts, they aren't good or bad. Just use local minimum if in contrast with finding the global minimum. Maxima and minima are often heard used as singular items, but I would avoid this in technical writing.

Comment: If you explained more clearly (what is the metaphorical or at least metonymical sense of 'local minimum' you're intending here? Is this a common usage?) we might be able to offer advice. But what is the point for looking for synonyms of 'become stuck / trapped / becalmed ... in' if the context makes them inappropriate ('becalmed in a local minimum' sounds ludicrous, while 'entrenched' fits the metaphor somewhat better)?